# Rails. Form submit contains nested model, call method from models controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Class Foo has many Bar(s)

I have a form which contains the nested class Bar and when the form submits I would like Bar
that was built to have an IP address associated to it from the server.
My issue is I do not know how to call a method through params to set the IP in Bar when Foo is created

In the Foo controller

```
def new
 @foo = Foo.new
 @foo.bars.build
end

def create
  @foo.Foo.create(params[:foo])
  if @foo save 
     #error code
     #b = Bar.find(params[:bar_id])
     # b.setIP request.remote_ip
  end
end
```

Form

```
<%= form_for @foo do |f| %>
    <%= f.label "Comment : " %>
    <%= f.fields_for :bars do |comment_form| %>
        <%= comment_form.text_area :comment %>
        <%= f.label "Terms of Service" %>
        <%= comment_form.check_box :terms %>

        <% end %>
<%= f.submit "Submit"%>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post your form as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
def create
  @foo = Foo.new(params[:foo])
  @foo.bars[0] = request.remote_ip
  if @foo save 
     #it's ok
  end
end
```

Explanation: when you have nested attributes, you create Foo and one or more Bars (one on many relationship). In your case, you make only one Bar, but that doesn't change the fact you have one on many relationship, you just have one element in bars. So, you put bars[0] to access first and only element of your bars array (ActiveRecord::Relation).

Comment: It worked, thank you!, would you mind explaining the reason behind having to select the first element? Is this purely due to the created_at value?